# stitch video side by side

Tags: android, video, android-mediacodec

I am new to decoding and encoding videos. I have a special requirement, where i need to capture the video from front camera and record the screen at the same time. Once done I need to stitch both videos sides by side. The videos will have same length and resolution.

How can I stitch the videos? I have seen MediaCodec API from the documentation. But it is too complex to understand for the beginners. The configuration requires a Surface, But I don't think my requirement needs a SurfaceView, as I am not going to play the video onto the surface. All i need is to stitch each frame from both videos side by side and encode them to MP4 format.

Is it achievable, from Android Framework. Or i need to rely on 3rd party library like FFMPEG?

Comment: You can render you camera to a surfaceview/textureview then use MediaProjection and VirtualDisplay as input surface for the encoder

Comment: @E.Abdel I am new to Encoding, I haven't used VirtualDisplay as well. Is it possible to elaborate more information. I hope you understood my requirement. I need to capture the screen and save it as a video. Also At the same time I need to use front capture to capture the video and save it as a video too. Finally I need to patch the videos side by side and also save it as a Video. Please provide more information. I will even come in chat.